# Incrementing basket items Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, logic

I am trying to write some logic that will evaluate if an item already exists in a basket and if it does increment the items quantity by 1 when the user adds the product and if not create a new record (the creating a new record bit is working well).

```
def create  
   @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
   @basket = current_basket

    if @basket.items.exists?(product_id: @product.id)
        current_basket.items.find(conditions: {:product_id => @product.id}).increment! :quantity
    else
        Item.create!(basket_id: @basket.id, product_id: @product.id, quantity: 1, price: @product.price)
    end

    redirect_to baskets_show_path

end
```

The error I am getting is `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: id.conditions: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."basket_id" = ? AND "id"."conditions" = '--- :product_id: 2 ' LIMIT 1`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `find_by` instead of conditions:

```
def create  
   @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
   @basket = current_basket

    if @basket.items.exists?(product_id: @product.id)
        current_basket.items.find_by(product_id: @product.id).increment! :quantity
    else
        Item.create!(basket_id: @basket.id, product_id: @product.id, quantity: 1, price: @product.price)
    end

    redirect_to baskets_show_path

end
```

Comment: Ha I was literally just trying `find_by` - this works a treat thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`first_or_create` might be helpful. See [API Dock ActiveRecord::Relation first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create). Of course, your needs are more complex than what is provided in the doc since the item has multiple identifying criteria.

I tested this out with a model in the app I have open and it seemed to do the trick (the model has a lot of validations I didn't want to mess with so I believe the actual create failed on that).

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @basket = current_basket

  item = Item.where({basket_id:  @basket.id,
                     product_id: @product.id,
                     price:      @product.price})
             .first_or_create(quantity: 0)
  item.increment! :quantity

  redirect_to baskets_show_path
end
```

So basically what's going on is, you set item to the item in the basket if it's there, or create it if it's not with the info you were already seeking, as well as an initial quantity of zero. Then, you increment by 1.

One other note is that you may want to confirm you need both instance variables. If just @basket is needed in the view, consider dropping the @ from all the product references. An explanation of why and how to keep controllers skinny is in [Jumpstart Lab's Slimming Controllers](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/controllers/slimming_controllers.html).